# Scaling down a raster image

Tags: image-processing

I have a raster image (A) of size 20x20 and I want to scale it down to a size of 10x10 (B).

Naturally in the resulting picture B one pixel will represent 4 pixels shaped 2x2 from A.

Is it possible to give a canonical answer to how the pixel values of B have to be calculated if no neighbouring pixels (surrounding the 2x2 subset) in A should be taken into account? Mean, maximum or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is the most widely used method. The nearest neighbor down-sampling algorithm is the fastest but least accurate.

Note that when you are trying to down-scale an image by half, the bilinear sampling algorithm becomes the average (mean as you mentioned):

```
x1[i/2][j/2] = (x[i][j] + x[i+1][j] + x[i][j+1] + x[i+1][j+1]) / 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend bilinear.

Beware that the default setting of most image editing apps is [bicubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) interpolation.

Bicubic makes sense for a wide range of scaling: up/down, photo/vector ([comparisons here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms)).  But when scaling down by a power of two, bilinear results in less distortion.

In this image, I have resized part of an "R" character using bilinear sampling from ImageMagick's `-scale` option.  (In this case, the original image was larger by a power of 2, so we are taking the mean.)

[image: Image shrunk by ImageMagick with -scale]

This is bicubic scaling with The GIMP's "cubic" option.  Notice how a few extra bright and dark "ringing" pixels were introduced, which make the edge appear sharper, but also look a bit dirty under close inspection.

[image: Image shrunk by The GIMP with cubic scaling]

The effect is even stronger when scaling with ImageMagick's `-geometry` or `-resize` option.

[image: Image shrunk by ImageMagick with -resize]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer (bilateral is good) can be balanced by the luminance quantization (from 1-bit black and white or true color), and the fact that your image is very small, so standard statistics don't apply here.

Indeed, a mean over $4$ pixels is generally not an integer, and will be rounded at the end. If you stick to $2\times2$ blocks, I would suggest to take the median of the four values: get rid of the `min` and the `max` of the four, and take the "nearest" integer (`ceil` or `floor` depending on whether you want a darker or brighter icon), and the  `min` or `max` of the mean of the two remaining pixels. I expect this to limit "intermediate luminance borders" that may not be useful at this size, and avoids grays on low-quantization images. I would treat the corners by "duplicating" the corner value (to limit the chances of an ugly color change at the borders): you will get $5$ pixel values, and then the standard median will be an integer.

More involved processing may resort to averaging $4\times 4$ patches, with a lower weight for the 10 surrounding pixels.

Of course, the effectiveness depends on the morphology of yoour image: is it flat, smoothly varying or stochastic?

Honestly, I suspect this proposal won't change dramatically the result on standard displays.